# Difference between const and static readonly for string obfuscation?

Tags: .net, obfuscation

We run our .NET binaries through an obfuscator (with at least string obfuscation enabled), and later in the build process make some basic checks to validate this.  I was surprised to notice that by changing strings from `static readonly string` to `const string`, the changed strings were now visible in plain text when viewing the disassembled code (via `ildasm` output).

**With regards to string obfuscation, what is the difference between `const string` and `static readonly string`?**

EDIT:
For the sake of example, here's a small program:

```
class Program
{
    private const string MyConstString = "MyConstString";
    private static readonly string MyStaticReadonlyString = "MyStaticReadonlyString";

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string myLocalString = "myLocalString";

        Console.WriteLine(MyConstString);
        Console.WriteLine(MyStaticReadonlyString);
        Console.WriteLine(myLocalString);

        Console.WriteLine("Hit <ENTER> to exit");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

After looking at the .il code, the only value in plain text is for the `const string`.  This is true for two different obfuscation tools:

```
.field private static literal string a = "MyConstString"       // using Dotfuscator
.field private static literal string '[SOH]' = "MyConstString" // using RedGate SmartAssembly
```

Comment: With your obfuscator, will the string `"Foo"` be obfuscated in the following code? `Console.WriteLine("Foo");`

Comment: @DanielHilgarth Yes, that's obfuscated.

Comment: @Blam Also happens with RedGate's SmartAssembly 6

Answer (score 5):

For `const` fields, their value simply has to be included directly in the assembly, there is no way around that. That's because the compiler has to be able to get the value of such field, without executing any of your custom code.

With `static readonly` fields, an obfuscator can use the static constructor to execute any code it wants, which means they can be obfuscated.

Comment: Why couldn't the obfuscator modify the const value and adjust every place that uses the const value?

Comment: Because it can't possibly know what “every other place” is. You could be retrieving the value of the `const` using reflection and the obfuscator wouldn't be able to adjust that. And with `public` `const`s (in `public` types), it's even worse, because anyone could be using it from outside.

Comment: the same argument could be made for static readonly strings as well, right?  the obfuscator has no idea if values are read via reflection or if they're used externally but it obfuscated those anyway.

Comment: @jglouie But loading obfuscated `readonly` field through reflection will still work, because after the obfuscated code is executed, you get the right value. With `const`s, the difference is there can't be any code.

Answer (score 0):

If it's static then the string value exist in the program's data segment, where it has an address and is referred to (in the code) by its address.

Whereas if it's const then it exists a string literal in the code segment.

Comment: How does that affect string obfuscation?

Comment: I made this answer 'community wiki' because I'm not sure that this answer is correct, but I didn't delete it in case it's helpful.

Comment: @jglouie It depends on how your obfuscator is implemented: for example, perhaps the obfuscator decrypts the data segment at run-time, or decrypts string values just in time when they're read from the data segment.